# why is text always centered to canvas

Tags: text, svg, fabricjs

When loading a SVG and rendering it to the canvas, the text contained in the path group is always centered. In the example below the text should be placed in the upper left corner.

**SVG:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="269.29px" height="269.29px" viewBox="0 0 269.29 269.29" xml:space="preserve">
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 7.5107 14.2222)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12">Text in the corner</text>
</svg>
```

**JS:**

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(uri, function (svg, options) {
            var group = new fabric.PathGroup(svg, options);
            canvas.add(group);
        });
```

Any rect, circle etc. within the pathgroup would be displayed as expected. So why is my text not displayed properly?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used fabric.js, but you're probably missing the `x` and `y` attributes. Also, add `text-anchor="start"` so it's easier to position:

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 7.5107 14.2222)" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0">Text in the corner</text>
```

Comment: Note that x and y both default to 0, so if that's what you want then you don't need to specify these attributes.

Comment: But OP is converting from SVG to canvas via fabric.js, which might not be rendering according to spec (just a theory).

Comment: Setting the text-anchor doesn't solve the problem for me. I doubt the rendering in fabric.js misunderstands the translation of the text element.

Comment: Here is a fiddle which depicts the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YA93m/1/ The text should be within the red square but is off. the black squares are used to ensure absolute positioning within the PathGroup using x and y attributes works as expected.

Comment: It seems that fabric.js does not support the text-anchor property, open a ticket https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues